# Zk 6 : Internet explorer in compatibility mode

Tags: java, internet-explorer, meta-tags, zk

we have a website deployed on Internet Explorer v8 in compatibility mode.
Unfortunately, Zk doesnt manage compatibility very well.

For moment, we have added a meta tag in order to force the engine.

```
<? meta http-equiv="X-U-Compatible" content="IE=8" ?>
```

But the result is not good.

Is it normal to not have the same result than with a IE 8 (no compatibility mode) ?
The result is near to be good with the meta which force the content with IE7 engine, but others components are impacted (menubar for example).

How to manage properly that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start out by using a standard doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You can still use the `x-ua-compatible` header if you like, or the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This forces the document into IE8 Standards Mode. In IE7 the document will appear in IE7 Standards Mode, and in IE9+ the document will show in IE8 Standards Mode.

Once your document is in Standards Mode, you can expect more consistent behavior and rendering. At that point you need to identify the areas that are inconsistent between browsers, and deal with those on a case-by-case basis.

We're here to help, when that time comes. Until then, have a read through [Specifying Legacy Document Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).